# SOAP API Uncaught SoapFault exception

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to upload a torrent into torcache.net, using their SOAP API.

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://torcache.net/torcache.wsdl');
$info_hash = $client->cacheTorrent(base64_encode(file_get_contents('test.torrent')));

print_r($info_hash);
?>
```

Here's what I receive:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Found in D:\Web\data\localweb\test.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient-&gt;__doRequest('&lt;?xml version=&quot;...', 'http://torcache...', 'urn:xmethods-de...', 1, 0)
#1 D:\Web\data\localweb\test.php(4): SoapClient-&gt;__call('cacheTorrent', Array)
#2 D:\Web\data\localweb\test.php(4): SoapClient-&gt;cacheTorrent('ZDg6YW5ub3VuY2U...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in D:\Web\data\localweb\test.php on line 4
```

Comment: Change your WSDL from http to https. Not sure if it will make a difference (and reading from phone so can't test) but noticed that difference between your code and their sample (and a torrent site may be that picky, though you would think they could just redirect)

Comment: And maybe try adding "./" in front of your test.torrent... May be looking in the wrong directory

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php), see if you can get any help.

or

Try this:

```
<?php 
try {  
    $x = @new SoapClient("http://torcache.net/torcache.wsdl");  
} catch (Exception $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: you could call your cacheTorrent(); inside try - catch and see if it helps

Comment: It returns me "Not Found", I have no idea what that means. The file is there, I've checked 5 times...

Comment: @TheBootyBay In that case try SoapClient::__getFunctions() it will prints all the function that belongs to wsdl. If you are able to see cacheTorrent() then function exist, then may be you're passing wrong parameters or there's something wrong in function definition

Comment: It says: string cacheTorrent(string $torrent)

Comment: See if you're getting data by using file_get_contents('test.torrent'). Try passing any dummy string to the cache function and see if its reaching the function body.

Comment: It gives me the exact same error when I pass different string (even without base64encode) - Not Found... I'm wondering is this a default SOAP error, or torcache.net error... They have POST script for upload, I might consider use it, instead SOAP.